# Case statements with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server

I have these two select statements that are using three tables. I need to be able to create a table from these and say if select statement 1 then assign the user a value = 10, if select statement 2 then assign user_id a value = 7. In my new table I would have the user_id and value it was assigned if the case statement evaluates to true. I keep getting syntax errors for any case statements I write

```
SELECT m.user_id,f.manager_id
from sales b
JOIN promotions m on b.user_id = m.user_id
JOIN promotions f on b.user_sub_id = f.user_id
where m.address = f.address
and m.post = '95103'

SELECT m.user_id,f.manager_id
from sales b
JOIN promotions m on b.user_id = m.user_id
JOIN promotions f on b.user_sub_id = f.user_id
where m.address = f.address
and m.post = '98746'
AND f.address <> 'NULL' AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM payments c
WHERE c.member_id = b.user_sub_id AND
c.status <> 'NULL'
AND c.info = 'T'
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case statements with alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963293/case-statements-with-alias)

Comment: It looks like Migo has already answered the question. However, I wanted to point out that, while `f.address <> 'NULL'` and `c.status <> 'NULL'` wouldn't cause syntax errors, I don't think they will work the way you expect them to (unless those columns will literally contain the string `'NULL'`. If, on the other hand, they will just be `NULL`, you need to use `f.address IS NOT NULL` and `c.status IS NOT NULL` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you done so far? No case statement needed.

```
select * 
into #Output
from (
-- select statement 1
select 10 as UserValue
, m.user_id
, f.manager_id

union all

-- select statement 2
select 7 as UserValue
, m.user_id
, f.manager_id 
) a
```